# call a procedure with table as IN parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, user-defined-types

I have the following code which works very nice:

```
declare
  v_order_id oe.orders.order_id%type := 1;

  v_order_item pkg_order_management.to_order_list := pkg_order_management.to_order_list();
begin

  v_order_item.extend(2);
  v_order_item(1).product_id :=  2289;
  v_order_item(1).quantity :=  2;

  v_order_item(2).product_id :=  2058;
  v_order_item(2).quantity :=  5;
  pkg_order_management.prc_create_order(240, v_order_item, v_order_id);
  dbms_output.put_line('it was created the order: ' || v_order_id);
end;
```

but I want to call the pkg_order_management.prc_create_order procedure like

```
declare
  v_order_id oe.orders.order_id%type := 1;
begin
  pkg_order_management.prc_create_order(240, ((2289, 2),(2058, 5)), v_order_id);
  dbms_output.put_line('it was created the order: ' || v_order_id);
end;
```

Here is the types  definition from the package:

```
type t_order_item is record
  ( product_id      oe.order_items.product_id%type
  , quantity        oe.order_items.quantity%type);

type to_order_list is table of t_order_item;
```

When I call the procedure as in 2nd case, I receive the following error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'PRC_CREATE_ORDER'

Surely, my call type is wrong but I have no idea how to solve this.
Can you give me a hint, please?

Comment: Why do you want to pass values to your procedure like this: `pkg_order_management.prc_create_order(240, ((2289, 2),(2058, 5)), v_order_id);`? It's pretty horrible to write and nasty to read.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The code is very ugly but it is for a training purpose. Beautifying the code is another topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PL/SQL record types are not object-oriented constructs. So we can't use them as flexibly as we can actually Objects.

If you want to pass an inline array you need to define your types using SQL:

```
create or replace type t_order_item is object
  ( product_id     number
  , quantity       number);
/

create or replace  type to_order_list is table of t_order_item; 
/
```

Note that this means you can no longer use %TYPE referencing to define the attributes of `t_order_item`.

Now your call to the procedure will look like this:

```
begin 
   pkg_order_management.prc_create_order(240
              , to_order_list(t_order_item(2289, 2)
                            , t_order_item(2058, 5)
                 ), v_order_id);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper call would be this:

```
pkg_order_management.prc_create_order(
   240, 
   pkg_order_management.to_order_list( 
       t_order_item(2289, 2),
       t_order_item(2058, 5)
   ), 
   v_order_id
);
```

... but do you really want such an ugly code?

`pkg_order_management.prc_create_order(240, v_order_item, v_order_id);` looks more beautiful to me.

Comment: running your code give me:
PLS-00201: identifier 'T_ORDER_ITEM' must be declared

Comment: Maybe a typo. Is `t_order_item` created in the same schema? Otherwise use `pkg_order_management.t_order_item`

Comment: Yes, both types, to_order_list and t_order_item are defined in package specification, in same schema.

Comment: Check the other answers. For, `t_order_item` you must define an `OBJECT` type not a `RECORD`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OBJECT` not `RECORD`.

Please red this:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm

Then you can use this nice notation:

```
CREATE TYPE t_order_item AS OBJECT (
    product_id      NUMBER,
    quantity        NUMBER
);
/

CREATE TYPE to_order_list IS TABLE OF t_order_item;
/



DECLARE
    v_order_id NUMBER;

    PROCEDURE prc_create_order (a NUMBER, order_list to_order_list, o_order_id OUT NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        NULL;
    END;

BEGIN
    prc_create_order(240, to_order_list(
                t_order_item(2289, 2),
                t_order_item(2058, 5)
                )
    , v_order_id);
END;
/
```